# When I want to use the python reportlab to save a pdf ,I get the trouble when using path with nonASCII characters?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab, python-unicode

i write some simply function to produce pdf from reportlab ,but when the path is nonASCII(for example chinese) there comes problems `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 3: invalid continuation byte`. and when the path is all ASCII everything is fine.

my code is very  simply ,just like

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4, landscape  
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Image  
from reportlab.lib.units import inch  
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab import rl_settings
import reportlab.lib.pagesizes

filename_pdf = path + path.split('/')[-2]+'.pdf'
c = canvas.Canvas(filename_pdf, pagesize=maxsize )
#some code
c.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename_pdf = filename_pdf.decode('gbk','ignore')
```

Comment: thank you ,i can solve my problem using your method .but i can't understand why. can you explain it a little more detail?

Comment: @mrbean pleasure. filename_pdf originally is encoded in gbk. This is determined by OS and the execution environment. You need to decode it to make it recognizable for further processing. Otherwise python will think of it as ASCII and naturally raise an exception.